# Error when connecting to hello world yesod example on Windows 8

Tags: yesod

I start the executable (after building it with cabal) and it says "Application launched, listening on port 3000." Next I connect to it with my web browser and the console says "threadWaitRead requires -threaded on Windows, or use System.IO.hWaitForInput." The web browser never connects. Not sure what this is actually recommending I do to resolve the problem.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, QuasiQuotes, MultiParamTypeClasses,
             TemplateHaskell, OverloadedStrings #-}
import Yesod

data HelloWorld = HelloWorld

mkYesod "HelloWorld" [parseRoutes|
/ HomeR GET
|]

instance Yesod HelloWorld

getHomeR :: Handler RepHtml
getHomeR = defaultLayout [whamlet|Hello World!|]

main :: IO ()
main = warpDebug 3000 HelloWorld
```

Comment: hello reltone, hi michael. I am also having this problem, with warp on windows XP. I used haskell platform 2012.2.0.0. I built cabal-dev through MINGW, then built my app through cabal-dev. Compiling with -threaded suppresses the error message, but does not fix the problem. The application does not reply to requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're compiling the executable, but using `-threaded` sounds like it would solve the problem, e.g.:

```
ghc --make hello-yesod.hs -threaded
hello-yesod.exe
```

Comment: I compiled it the way the yesod hello world tutorial told me.

Comment: hi michael, I don't have the details, but the problem have been introduced by a recent commit. I found it while reading the git changelog. Rolling back to 1.3.1 suppresses the problem. Regards,

Comment: Paul R: thank you! It seems that a recent optimization only works for Windows. I've released a new version of Warp (1.3.3.3), which seems to run correctly for me on Windows. Can you try it out? @reltone Paul's answer is the correct one. it would be best if you could update the checkmark appropriately.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman : hi, I just tried and it works indeed, thanks. Also, it still requires -threaded in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has probably been introduced here : http://hdiff.luite.com/cgit/warp/commit?id=1.3.1.1

Enforce cabal to use the 1.3.1 version of warp and things should work as expected. It still requires to be linked with -threaded, in my experience.